# Intellij Attach Sources does not seem to work

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have followed various posts about how to attach sources in IJ. None are working. Here I will walk through this.  I am on IJ 13.1.2

We have a library with missing sources here (not in maven):

[image]

Let us try to attach the sources using the "Attach sources" link in upper right:

[image]

But nothing changes : the sources are not attached.  So this is the first bug.

[image]

Now let us try by navigating to the library within the Project View:
[image]

Well that seems to have made progress!

[image]

However: we STILL DO NOT HAVE SOURCES when we click on a class within that library, the message "Sources not found" still occurs.

Is this supposedly fixed?  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the source jar file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sources extension from jar to zip and then import.

Comment: Tried that. No change.